# Maven module order changes on the same profile

Tags: maven, build, maven-profiles

I have project which has 3 pom files, and 2 maven profiles :prod and dev. The problems is that when I run my dev profile with cmd

```
mvn clean install -Pdev
```

it builds project with order :

1. backend,
2. frontend

When I build project with prod profile, it builds project with order :

1. frontend
2. backend

Which is the way i want. But when I run cmd

```
mvn clean install
```

It needs to build project with dev profile, and it does it but in this order : 1.frontend, 2.backend.

and this is the problem, it changes module order. Here is the main pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.main</groupId>
<artifactId>Main</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Main</name>
<description>Main Parent Project</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>backend</module>
    <module>frontend</module>
</modules>
```

here is backend pom.xml

```
 <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
<name>backend</name>
<description>Backend Project</description>



<parent>
    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>Main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>



<dependencies>
 ...
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <profiles>${spring-profiles}</profiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>dev</profileActive>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>prod</profileActive>
        </properties>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
                    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and here is frontend pom.xml

```
   <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
<name>frontend</name>
<description>Frontend Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>Main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/webapp</workingDirectory>
                <nodeVersion>v6.0.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>2.7.1</npmVersion>
                <nodeDownloadRoot>https://nodejs.org/dist/</nodeDownloadRoot>
                <npmDownloadRoot>https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/</npmDownloadRoot>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm rebuild node-sass</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>

                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>rebuild node-sass</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>bower install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bower</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>gulp</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>gulp</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>

                            <arguments>${gulpProfile}</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>dev</profileActive>
            <gulpProfile>-d</gulpProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            <profileActive>prod</profileActive>
            <gulpProfile>-p</gulpProfile>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Can you help me and tell why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind of thing is resolved because your frontend would be dependent upon the jar produced by your backend.

So, even if it does not have a compile time dependency you can still add one at `provided` scope:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
   <version>${project.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will tell the maven reactor that it must always build the backend first, without changing the resulting artifact that is built.

Answer (score 0):

- First remove `<activation>` tag from backend/pom.xml. I hoping that you need keep only one profile active at a time by default and which should be `dev`
- Remove the dependency mentioned in backend/pom.xml from `prod` profile. Your `fronend` project should be depend on `backend`.
- Add the `backend` dependency in frontend/pom.xml as below (not in any specific profile)

Code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
  <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
  <version>${project.version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now try below commands

```
mvn clean    // (default profile `dev`)
mvn clean --activate-profiles prod     // (with override profile `prod`)
```

Comment: @Bohdan Levkovych, did above steps helped you to resolve your issue?